# How to read last float number of binary file in Python in a fast way

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I have a binary file, that stores all float numbers. I would like to get the final number in that file in Python.

What's the fastest way?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the file via a hex dump?

Comment: What is the not-so-fast way you are currently using?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file is just tightly packed floats,

```
import struct

s = struct.Struct("<f")  # single little-endian float

with open("binary-blob.dat", "rb") as f:
   f.seek(-s.size, 2)  # seek to the end of the file minus the size of the float
   buf = f.read(s.size)  # read the float
   last_float, = s.unpack(buf)  # unpack the float
```

You can change the struct specifier depending on the endianness and width of your floats.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought float is of minimal size 4(float16) in python. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Did you try the program? `s.size` is 4...